# WPF C# UI : New Window or Tab?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, window, tabs

Our WPF application in the current design opens new windows for list screen.We don't have restrictions on the number of windows you open etc.We are using a ribbon control and well it has tab support.Which is better a new window or a tab? (With windows 7 having a better group of window management etc) Should I go in for tab or leave it as window. I can't make the detail screen tab since well the user click of a item in the grid to select and edit.Any valid suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabs in a Ribbon shouldn't change the view. The Ribbon is an enhanced toolbar, not a view changer.

If your using the MS Ribbon via OfficeUI, then there is a stipulation in the design guidelines that the view should never change the appearance of the ribbon (apart from loading context tabs) and that they ribbon should never wholesale change the view.

In regards to your question, do you mean that you have list/grid and you want a view to be able to change the data in the row. Eg. they double click a row, a view appears that gives them the ability to edit that row?

Comment: currently user click on ribbon button it opens a window which shows the grid view and when user clicks a item it opens a detail view

Answer (score 1):

The right way is to ask your users what they like more. If you can't ask users, ask yourself - what you find more convenient - to open\close windows or switch between tabs. I wouldn't rely on win7 task bar as it's grouping behavior can be disabled or users may use another OS. Also I would suggest to check Microsoft guidelines for using ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to see more than one pane's content at once?  Windows allow this, but tabs do not.

Tabs make management of the various windows easier at the expense of some flexibility.

Are your users likely to be running on multiple windows?

It is really hard to give a confident answer to you on this one without knowing more about your application and your user's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 displays multiple previews on grouped windows of the application, however in case of tab, like IE, you will have to write quite a good custom code to show your tabs in preview of Windows 7 taskbar, which in case of Multiple Windows, it will be done automatically.

Not only that, Windows 7 also lets you put seven toolbar buttons on the preview windows, very few people knows about it because no application currently does it.

For tabs you will need to do extra programming to support multi window preview.

So its better to stay with multi window solution for now.

However in case of IE, if you try to use Windows 7 taskbar, the tabs dont align themselves in correct order of what is displayed in preview, it could be bug, but yes there might be certain limitations because when user chooses the tab to preview you will not be able to show them preview unless you make it active and thats why its little bad.

Comment: i dont want to add any windows 7 api code.i was just telling that windows 7 makes it easier to navigate many windows

Answer (score 0):

I recommend playing with Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome if you want to see tabs at their finest.
Notice that tabs can be teared out into a separate window and windows can be docked as tabs.